# onDragOver doesn't happen (in JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop

Why doesn't `onDragOver` event happen in the following example?

How to implement simplest drag behaviour, i.e. w/o clipboard things?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.DragEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DragTry extends Application {

   private Point2D dragVector = null;

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

      Pane root = new Pane();

      Pane node = new Pane();
      node.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLUE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, javafx.geometry.Insets.EMPTY)));
      node.setPrefWidth(100);
      node.setPrefHeight(50);
      node.setTranslateX(200);
      node.setTranslateY(200);

      node.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
         @Override
         public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println("odDragDetected");

            double x = event.getX();
            double y = event.getY();
            x -= node.getTranslateX();
            y -= node.getTranslateY();
            dragVector = new Point2D(x, y);
            node.startFullDrag();
         }
      });

      node.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
         @Override
         public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            System.out.println("onDragOver");

            double x = event.getX();
            double y = event.getY();
            x += dragVector.getX();
            y += dragVector.getY();
            node.setTranslateX(x);
            node.setTranslateY(y);
         }
      });

      node.setOnDragDone(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
         @Override
         public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            dragVector = null;
         }
      });

      root.getChildren().add(node);

      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);

      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.setTitle("DragTry");
      primaryStage.show();
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      DragTry.launch(args);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onDragXYZ` events are for clipboard drag events. For the other type of drag&drop feature you need to use the `onMouseDragXYZ` events instead. Furthremore it's better not to use the coordinates in the `Node`'s own coordinate system in case you're modifying.

```
node.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("odDragDetected");

        double x = event.getX();
        double y = event.getY();
        dragVector = node.localToParent(x, y).subtract(node.getTranslateX(), node.getTranslateY());
        node.startFullDrag();
    }
});

node.setOnMouseDragOver(new EventHandler<MouseDragEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseDragEvent event) {
        System.out.println("onDragOver");

        Point2D parentCoords = node.localToParent(event.getX(), event.getY());

        node.setTranslateX(parentCoords.getX() -dragVector.getX());
        node.setTranslateY(parentCoords.getY() -dragVector.getY());
    }
});

node.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        dragVector = null;
    }
});
```

However since only a single node is involved in the gesture, there is no need to use drag events. You could simply use `onMousePressed` instead of `onDragDetected` and `onMouseDragged` instead of `onMouseDragOver`.

Comment: It appeared to me, the `startFullDrag` is not needed at all

Comment: @Dims The full drag mode will allow mouse events to be delivered to nodes other than the node on which the drag was initiated. There are three different dragging modes: see the [`MouseEvent` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html) for a description of how each one works; briefly, `startFullDrag()` or `startDragAndDrop()` each select one of the non-default modes.

Answer (score 7):

First, you need to call `startDragAndDrop`, instead of `startFullDrag`. The different drag modes are described in the [documentation for `MouseEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html).  Additionally, one annoying part of the drag and drop API is that dragging isn't activated unless you add something to the dragboard:

```
  node.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
     @Override
     public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("odDragDetected");

        double x = event.getX();
        double y = event.getY();
        x -= node.getTranslateX();
        y -= node.getTranslateY();
        dragVector = new Point2D(x, y);

        Dragboard db = node.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
        ClipboardContent cc = new ClipboardContent();
        cc.putString("Something");
        db.setContent(cc);
     }
  });
```

Comment: Important detail about placing something on the dragboard!  Thanks.